# What is the scope of pega tool in future is it worth learning over machine learning?

Tags: automation, pega, rda

I recently joined a company there they ask me if i want i can in project where pega is used so i want to know that  What is the scope of pega tool in future is it worth learning over machine learning?

Comment: Now i am in your situation what are your thoughts?

Answer (score 3):

Pega and machine learning are two very different things which can not be compared. At one end machine learning is a hard core technical field on the other pega is a tool which is built using model driven development(Non Technical) where no code needs to be written. It basically is for non technical people who can automate there business processes even if they are not technically sound.

The main characteristic of a Model-Driven Development platform is that an application is not programmed but modelled by means of visual artifacts that can be understood by the business.

Now, it completely depends on your career aspiration whether you want to go for pega or machine learning. In my opinion if you are not a techie then pega is the thing for you but if you want to explore core technologies then I will not suggest you to go for pega.